# Merge data from two tables to one

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Software: SQL Server Management Studio 2008

I am getting a pool of data in 2 tables. I want to sort out the data and paste it in a third table according to certain requirements.

This is table 1 (master.dbo.FloatTable)

```
Date and Time   Militm  TagIndex    Val Status  Marker
8-6-15 10:30 AM  671      0              78      B
8-6-15 10:30 AM  671      1              76      B
8-6-15 10:30 AM  671      2              76      B
8-6-15 10:30 AM  671      3              72      B
8-6-15 10:30 AM  671      4              70      B
8-6-15 10:30 AM  671      5              72      B
```

Table 2 (master.dbo.TagTable)

```
TagName                      TagIndex   TagType TagDataType
Capacity_9251_Ashift_History    0          2        0
Capacity_9251_Bshift_History    1          2        0
Capacity_9251_Cshift_History    2          2        0
Capacity_9252_Ashift_History    3          2        0
Capacity_9252_Bshift_History    4          2        0
```

I am merging them as 
Table 3 (CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData)

under column heading
TagIndex, Date, PressNumber, Shift, Capacity, Production

The code:

```
    DELETE 
    CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData 

    INSERT 
    INTO CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData (Date, TagIndex)

    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),DateAndTime,103), TagIndex
    FROM master.dbo.FloatTable
    WHERE Status != 'U' AND TagIndex BETWEEN 0 AND 320
    ORDER BY TagIndex 

    UPDATE CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData
    SET CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData.PressNumber =SUBSTRING(TagName,10,len(master.dbo.TagTable.TagName)-24),
        CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData.Shift =RIGHT(SUBSTRING(TagName,10,len(master.dbo.TagTable.TagName)-22),1)
    FROM CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData 
    INNER JOIN master.dbo.TagTable
    ON CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData.TagIndex = master.dbo.TagTable.TagIndex AND master.dbo.TagTable.TagIndex BETWEEN 0 AND 320

    UPDATE CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData
    SET CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData.Capacity = master.dbo.FloatTable.Val
    FROM CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData 
    INNER JOIN master.dbo.FloatTable
    ON CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData.TagIndex = master.dbo.FloatTable.TagIndex AND master.dbo.FloatTable.TagIndex BETWEEN 0 AND 320
    WHERE master.dbo.FloatTable.Status != 'U'
```

This joins the first 321 rows and I get a perfect result as I expect
This is the result I get

```
    TagIndex    Date    PressNumber Shift   Capacity    Production
      0       06-08-15    9251        A        78           NULL                                                            
      1       06-08-15    9251        B        76           NULL                                                                        
      2       06-08-15    9251        C        80           NULL                                                                                    
      3       06-08-15    9252        A        90           NULL
```

and on and on till tagindex 320

Now I also need to merge the production data that I get from tagindex 321 till 640
I was thinking of comparing the press number from CuringData table to the TagTable and get the corresponding index number. Then take that index number and get the corresponding value from the FloatTable and paste it to the CuringData on the appropriate IndexNumber

I just cannot get my head around coding this since I dont know much about the SQL Language (I'm sure you can sense that when you read the code I have written)

Need help sorting this out.

Comment: Have you considered using a UNION

Comment: Well how would I match the data though, I mean I only need to look from Index 321 to 640 and match the data as written above

Answer (score 0):

[1]first you make table "x" as per your requirement.

[2]use left outer join and make select query as per your data needs

select *
from FloatTable a
left outer join TagTable b on a.TagIndex=b.TagIndex
left outer join production  c on ...................

[3] user below command :
insert into x
select *
from FloatTable a
left outer join TagTable b on a.TagIndex=b.TagIndex
left outer join production  c on ...................

to insert into x table.

please send me proper table design so i can give you perfect query.

Comment: How can I send you the table design? The stuff that I have pasted above is the partial table. Only that the index goes till 641

Comment: One more thing to clarify

The capacity data that I have from index 0 to 320 in table 1 is sorted out and copied in another table (Table 3)

The PressNumber that I have taken from Table 2 and pasted to Table 3 correlate according to the TagIndex

Then there is the production data from index 321 to 640 (Table 1)
Now I need to take the PressNumbers from Table 3, get the corresponding tagindex from Table 2. Get the value of that tagindex from Table 2 and paste it back to Table 3 in that particular PressNumber NOT tagindex